# MigLayout panel growing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I have an outer pane (NetBeans `TopComponent` , let's call it "outer") and itside it I have some components and a `JScrollPane` ("scroll") with `JPanel` inside ("inner"))
The problem is, that I want the scroll to grow to fit the space in outer when it is manually resized, but when the inner resizes in the scroll, I want the scroll not to grow and remain stable.
When I write

```
outerGeneralPanel.add(scrollPane, 
                new CC().wrap().grow());
```

it allows the scroll to fit my outer TopComponent, but if the panel inside the scroll gets bigger, the scroll gets bigger too, and I don't want it.
Any ideas?